# Looking for howto document to install on Dell Inspiron 537

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 on my Dell Inspiron 537 and I get to the partitioning step after booting from the CD and clicking 'Install Ubuntu', There are no partitions visible in the window.  When I click on the + to add a partition, the installation hard freezes.

When I select the 'Try Ubuntu' option, I can see the partitions just fine:

[image]

In both cases, I get video corruption when mousing over buttons, and also when typing characters:

[image]

Ideas?

This system is currently running Vista, but I'm going to ditch it once I can get Linux installed.

The Inspiron 537 is not on the certified hardware list, and uses an Intel based chipset integral to the motherboard:

The video is integrated to the motherboard, and is Intel G41 Express chipset.

The SATA controller is also integrated and is Intel 82801 GB/GR/GH (ICH7 Family) - 27C0

Comment: When you choose «Try Ubuntu» — there's also should be a launcher to run the installation. Did you try it? Also, can you add the output — once the «Try Ubuntu» started — of `dmesg` and `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`? As you have a problem with letters, you can redirect it to a file, like `dmesg > dmesg.txt` the just copy it, and the file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, to a usb stick or to a visible partition.

Comment: Ah, and by the way, I'd suggest [to download the latest LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) instead of the one you having. You would need to upgrade either way, plus perhaps there could be added some fixes and workarounds… I'm strongly advice you to give it a try.